# SQL Query for Pattern Matching Like '* * * *'

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data table in postgres is;

[image]

I need to filter rows where schedule interval has four  `*` in the end (lets say expected result should return only row 1 and 2. Would appreciate a help with most appropriate SQL query.

```
dag_id      schedule_interval
a           "20,50 * * * *"
b           "0 * * * *"
c           {"type", "timedelta", "attrs" { ...
d           "0 1 * * * *"
```

Comment: `LIKE '%****'`.

Comment: Images of data makes it hard to see if there's a space character between every `*`...

Comment: RIGHT(schedule_interval, 4) = '****'

Comment: @jarlh there is space between *s and LIKE doesnt work `LIKE '%* * * *'` either

Comment: @MacGyver doesnt work either

Comment: What *exactly* is the stored value? Are there quotes around the value (as part of the value)? Are those single spaces between the *s? - a text (as copy of real data, not retyped) instead of an image would show that clearly

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/kJecv3lO

Comment: Sorry about that @khawarizmi, my eyesight wasn't the best when I saw the text.  I pasted the data using text, then highlighted it, and selected the editor button with "{}" to turn it into source code format

Comment: Also, when there is an answer that is correct, the person asking the question has the authority to click the green checkmark under the answer votes, and it'll improve the reputation of both the person asking and answering to show the internet readers which answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

As in data the `schedule_interval` field is of the format `"* * * * *"` therefore the last double quote should be taken into consideration while querying; below is correct answer built based on MacGyver's comment above

```
select dag_id, schedule_interval 
from dag 
where RIGHT(schedule_interval, 7)=' * * * *"'
```

Comment: You seem to be right about the quotes. The `RIGHT` approach, howver, is error-prone. You are comparing a string of seven characters with a a string of nine characters for instance, so you'll never get a match. I prefer `LIKE` for that reason.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner totally agree about making sure the length of the RIGHT function is the same as the string you're trying to match. But if you use LIKE you'll need to remember to escape the * so it is read literally and not as a wildcard.

Comment: @RickyTillson: Does PostgreSQL treat the * as a wildcard in `LIKE`? That would be news to me. It should only treat _ and % as wildcards, nothing else.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you're totally right, for some reason I was thinking of MySQL despite the tags

Comment: @RickyTillson: That makes no difference. MySQL's `LIKE` is as standard-compliant as Postgre's. The * has no special meaning there either.